# Any changes made in files, git creates untracked files in .history/

Tags: git

Hi I am working on a new project that I just cloned, any changes that I make in the files are creating new files in .history/, these files are untracked and as they are made with every there is quite a lot of them.  When I just make changes in existing files its a bit easier to commit, as I don't have to add them to it and after the commit a I can stash them all. But it is not really how I wanna work and I see that once I will need to add a new file this will be even more annoying.
I work in VS Code but in any other project the git flow works fine so I think it does not have to do anything with that. Doea anyone know how to avoid creating these files by git? Thanks

Comment: Git doesn't create that. Look elsewhere, I'll check VSCode config first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are created by VS Code, and not by git.
Just add .history folder to .gitignore file.
Create .gitignore file, and add there this line
`.history/`